# Getting error about redefinition even with guard

Tags: c++

I have a basic file I'm attempting to use.

```
#ifndef POINT_GUARD
#define POINT_GUARD

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) { }
    Point() :x(0), y(0) { }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

inline bool operator==(Point a, Point b) { return a.x==b.x && a.y==b.y; } 

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

inline bool operator!=(Point a, Point b) { return !(a==b); }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif // POINT_GUARD
```

Notice that it's wrapped in a guard. Now this is imported into two different files. I'm getting an error, though.

It complains as soon as it hits `struct Point` that it's a "Redefinition of Point". Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: What compiler do you use? maybe it just not support `ifndef`.

Comment: @Axilles I'm using Xcode 4.6 which I assume uses LLVM 4.2.

Comment: Does it occur when you rename Point to something else?

Comment: @mikbal Actually no, it doesn't give a warning when I do that. Odd. And no this isn't declared anywhere else.

Comment: @Yep This means your given code is correct (with `Point` definition). Problem should be in client code, where you h-file is used IMO. Make search for `Point` in you project - may be occasional redefinition?

Comment: @Axilles: Hmm, I searched the entire project and it's not defined anywhere else. This also works just fine when compiling on a different system.

Comment: Actually whoa. Before I was compiling on a PC, but now I'm on a Mac. Looks like there's a system type called Point that does something I have no idea in MacTypes.h. Is there a way I can undefine that?

Comment: You should put your code in a namespace to avoid type name collisions like this.

Comment: @Hbcdev: I wish I could, but this is for a homework assignment and I cannot change the wrappers given to me.

Comment: If you cannot change the header file, then the best you can do is a macro hack. `#include <MacTypes.h> #define Point MyPoint #include "Point.h"` That will redefine Point as MyPoint thoughout your code but leave it unchanged in MacTypes.h

Comment: You could put the #include in a namespace in the file where you use the header. Should work, I think.

Comment: @john That looks like a very nasty hack but I think it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error with the input given. I placed your code in `test.h`, and wrote this for `test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"
#include "test.h"
```

Running `g++ -Wall -c test.cpp` produces no errors or warnings, and running it through the pre-processor shows that `struct Point` is declared only once, so the guard is working.

I'd guess there's a declaration with the same name somewhere else, outside of the code you quoted?